# How to add schedule activity in calendar app odoo14

Tags: odoo

I try to add schedule activity in form view.But , when I click SCHEDULE button in mail activity wizard form, not displayed in chatter. But when I click  MARK  AS  DONE  or  DONE  &  SCHEDULE  NEXT  button,  displayed  in  chatter.  Here is my code.

```html
class MyMixedInCalendar(models.Model):
  _name = 'calendar.event'
  _inherit = ['calendar.event','\mail.activity.mixin','mail.thread']

  full_name = fields.Char()
```

Here is my view

```html
<record id ="calender_form_inherit" model ="ir.ui.view">
          <field name ="name">calendar.event</field>
          <field name ="model">calendar.event</field>
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_form"/>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <div class="oe_chatter" position="replace">
              <div class="oe_chatter">
                  <field name="message_follower_ids"/>
                    <field name="message_ids" />
                  <field name="activity_ids"/>
                </div>
            </div>
          </field>
        </record>
```